# Replicate Content Across Networks

Tags: 2007, content-deployment

A client is asking for a custom application to be created and deployed within the corporate intranet. Part of the requirements are to publish some of the content also available on the internet site. Both sites are built on SharePoint 2007 but they are on different farms and on different networks. Can the Content Deployment API (and associated tools) handle moving selected content across networks with no direct connectivity? Can we use web services? Has anybody done this sort of thing? If so what approaches have you taken?

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 1):

I did this back in the SP 2003 days using web services with great success.  So much so, we haven't migrated the solution to use the content deployment api yet.  You would still need to be able to communicate betweeen the two farms though.

Comment: Same experience here.  The web service layer makes it very easy to access content from anywhere.